# vue js prop equal to v-model

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, v-model, vue-props

Why changes take affect on also props when I set v-model equal to props in mount hook.

```
export default{
  props: {
    initial_value: Array,
  },

  data(){
     return { component_value: [] }
  },

   mounted(){
     this.component_value = this.initial_value;
   }
}
```

So when I make some changes to component_value it also take affect on initial_value.

I wanted to write whole my code here but just tried make it short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you code in mount hook, like this below

```
mounted() {
   this.component_value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initial_value));
}
```

It will the value of this.initial_value variable not by just reference but by data of it.
In JavaScript, a variable may store two types of data: primitive and reference. And this.initial_value has reference data since it's type is an array. For more explanation please read this article [source](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-primitive-vs-reference-values/)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do that is to clone your `initial_value`.

You can do that like this:

```
mounted() {
     this.component_value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initial_value));
   }
```

This should work.

You can check more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object).

Answer (score 0):

```
export default{
  props: ['initial_value'],

  data(){
     return { component_value: this.initial_value }
  }

}
```

This should work.

**EDIT:**

If you are going to change the props continuisly (reactivity), you must use a computed property, like this

```
computed: { 
      component_value(){ 
           return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initial_value) 
          } 
   }
```

Regards